# Is it possible to automatically embed bundle templates in project templates?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on a `Symfony 6` based project. Beside the project it self I have created some bundles which contain code I use in multiple projects.

### TL;DR:

Is it possible to **automatically** embed templates from such a bundle in a project specific template?

In general I am looking for something like this pseudo code:

```
// .../SomeProject/config/routes.yaml
...
my_user_admin:
    resource: '@MyUserBundle/config/admin_routes.yaml' 
    prefix: /admin
    embed_in_template: 'admin_routes.yaml::content'    <<< Is this possible?
```

### Details:

Assume `MyUserBundle` contains shared code to handle users in different projects. For example it contains controllers to list all registered users or edit a single user:

```
// .../MyBundle/config/routes/admin_routes.yaml
my_user_admin_user_list:
    path: /users
    controller: MyUserBundle\Controller\AdminController::userList

my_user_admin_user_details:
    path: /user/{user_id}
    controller: MyUserBundle\Controller\AdminController::userDetails


// .../MyBundle/src/Controller
public function userList(Request $request): Response {
    ...
    return $this->render('@MyUser/admin/user_list.html.twig', ['users' => $users]);
}

public function userDetails(Request $request): Response {
    ...
    return $this->render('@MyUser/admin/user_details.html.twig', [...]);
}


// .../MyBundle/templates/admin/user_list.html.twig
<table>
    {% for user in users %} 
        <tr><td>{{ user.name }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

In this example the `userList` controller does NOT output a complete page with header, body, etc. but only the HTML code of the user list itself.

This controller/route can easily be used in a projects which uses this bundle:

```
// .../SomeProject/config/routes.yaml
...
my_user_admin:
    resource: '@MyUserBundle/config/admin_routes.yaml' 
    prefix: /admin
```

`https://someproject.xx/admin/users` will now show the user list. But again only the pure user list without any surrounding HTML code.

### Question

Is it possible to tell Symfony to **automatically** embed the output of this controller/route with some other template?

For example the project specific template `.../SomeProject/templates/admin_base.html.twig` contains the HTML skeleton to be used for all admin backend pages of this project, including the nav menue, etc.

```
// .../SomeProject/templates/admin_base.html.twig
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <nav class="adamin_nav">...</nav>
        {% block content %}
             // user list of MyUserBundle\Controller\AdminController::userList should be here...
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

### Manual solutions

There a some solution to do this manually of course:

- Override `MyUserBundle\Controller\AdminController` within the project and render a different, project specific template based on `admin_base.html.twig`
- Do not import the routes from `MyUserBundle` but define a custom route and controller in `SomeProject` which uses `{{ render(controller(MyUserBundle\Controller\AdminController::userList))` in its template
- Override the bundle template by providing `.../SomeProject/templates/bundles/MyUserBundle/user_list.html.twig` which can then extend `admin_base.html.twig`. However, I do not know how to render the content of the parent template file in there.

While these solution would work, it would be very cumbersome. There is not only route/controller from one bundle which should be used in this way but multiple routes/controller from multiple bundles. One would have have to add a new route/controller/template override, etc. to the project for each bundle controller which should be added. Is this really the way to go?

Symfony is so flexible and provides so many options, I am not sure, that this is really the best option.

In general I am looking for something like this pseudo code:

```
// .../SomeProject/config/routes.yaml
...
my_user_admin:
    resource: '@MyUserBundle/config/admin_routes.yaml' 
    prefix: /admin
    embed_in_template: 'admin_routes.yaml::content'    <<< Is this possible?
```

Comment: Any reason `user_list.html.twig` doesn't extend a `base` or is this because you want the ability to auto-load multiple "partials"?

Comment: The bundle should only create the actual page content while the project is responsible to provide the page skeleton. So yes, this could be described as "partials" provided by the bundle, to be used within a project specific page.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in capability though I could be wrong.  Your render controller approach is probably your best bet.  I don't know if you have been around long enough to remember the FOSUserBundle which had similar capabilities.  Used to be by far the most popular non-Symfony bundle in any category but eventually went defunct partly because of these sorts of problems.  Sharing templates is hard.

Comment: yes. this is possible. I did something very similar in the Zikula Theme module. https://github.com/zikula/core/tree/main/src/system/ThemeModule and https://docs.ziku.la/LayoutDesign/Themes/requestresponsecycle.html

Comment: possible !== simple though...